# How to parse a JSON which is ["a#1", "b#2] in Java

Tags: java, json

My JSON response is

```
["a#1" , "b#2"]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically is the issue you're having? There is definitely more details you could put in this question.

Comment: I just called an api, which gives this type of response.

Comment: i want to know how to parse this

Comment: What do you mean by parse here ? Its an array object

Comment: How to read each element in this Arrray object

Comment: you can access index wise. Get the length of the array and just iterate over it.

Comment: Please can you help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery, the JavaScript code will be:

```
// url is your JSON source
$(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(i, v) {
            var w = v.split("#");
            // do something with w[0] and w[1]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I want to do this in Java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to convert json to pojos:
[GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
[Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)